# Reformat date string

Tags: javascript, date

Given a date string in yyyy-MM-dd format like 2018-08-09, how would I convert it to  yyyy/MM/dd format (2018/08/09) and dd/MM/yyyy format (09/08/2018) in javascript?

I have seen [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) but it is about how to format a javascript date while i want to format a javascript date string

Comment: Show us your Javascript code and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all the hyphens in the date String with slashes, you can split the String on `"-"` and join it on `"/"`.

```js
var dateStr = "2018-08-09";
var newDateStr = dateStr.split('-').join('/');//output is 2018/08/09
console.log(newDateStr);
```

To change a date String from `yyyy-MM-dd` format to `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you can split the String on `"-"`, reverse it, and join it on `"/"`.

```js
 var dateStr = "2018-08-09";
var newDateStr = dateStr.split('-').reverse().join('/');//output is 09/08/2018
console.log(newDateStr);
```